# NetSuite Saved Search Column Headings / Headers. Using SQL tags

Tags: html, netsuite

I am working in NetSuite to create a saved search where one column contains balances as of the last day last month. For example, today's date is 4/16/17 so using SQL code I was able to to retrieve the last day of the prior month--3/31/17. Is it possible to display date functions, e.g. {today} in Saved Search Column Headings?

Saved Search Results:

[image]

In the attached image, I'd like to be able to say "Last Period-End (3/31/17)" so the saved search user can see the as of date.

Any solution for this question or advice/work arounds on the topic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible. The header for a search results column is always the field name or formula type or you can use a custom label but it doesn't support formulas.

I know that is not the same but you can group the results by period.